# What is the Django way to add data to a form that is already instantiated?

Tags: django, django-forms

Suppose you have a `ModelForm` to which you have already binded the data from a `request.POST`. If there are fields of the ModelForm that I don't want the user to have to fill in and that are therefore not shown in the form (ex: the user is already logged in, I don't want the user to fill a 'author' field, I can get that from `request.user`), what is the 'Django' way of doing it ?

```
class RandomView(View):
    ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = RandomForm(request.POST)
        form.fill_remaining_form_fields(request) ### How would you implement this ???
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
```

I have tried adding the fields to the form instance (ex: `self.data['author'] = request.user`) but given its a `QueryDict` it is immutable so it clearly isn't the correct way of doing this.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Normally you don't: you set the `.author` of the `.instance` of the `form`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the Django documentation actually explains how to do this in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use (see the Note).